# Bootstrap examples with Express.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to get Bootstrap Carousel example to work with simple Express.js code, but I failed with always 404 returned code for those reference links in the html file. The index.html resides in /test/ folder, while the rest of the reference files are located in /test/docs/assets/js and /test/docs/assets/ico.

The Express.js simple code is as below:

```
app.get('/', function(request, response) {
response.sendfile('index.html');
});
```

The reference link part in the index.html is like:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="144x144" href="./docs/assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-144-precomposed.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="./docs/assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-114-precomposed.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="./docs/assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-72-precomposed.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="./docs/assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-57-precomposed.png">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="./docs/assets/ico/favicon.png">
```

I've tried with a different html file without the reference link and it works well. I also tried to tweak with something like app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/docs/assets/ico/')) but it doesn't work either.

How should I do to get it work correctly? I also found there isn't much examples about express.js; would you have any suggestion of the resources for study?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your directory structure looks like this:

```
app.js
index.html
docs/assets/ico/
```

Then try this as a minimal Express app:

```
// app.js
var express = require('express');
var app     = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname));

app.listen(8000);
```

Some explanation:

- `__dirname` is the directory in which `app.js` resides; since `index.html` and your asset files are located relative to that directory, we'll use that as the 'root' directory for `express.static`;
- you don't need a separate route for `/` if you have an `index.html`, because the static middleware will 'translate' a request for a directory to an `index.html` file in that directory;

**EDIT:** if you want to keep the separate route for `/`, make sure you include it before you include the static middleware. The reason for this is that middleware and routes are (generally) called in order of declaration; if you include the static middleware first, it will get to handle the requests for `/` and it will never reach your route handler:

```
// WRONG:
app.use(express.static(...));
app.get('/', ...);

// RIGHT:
app.get('/', ...);
app.use(express.static(...));
```

Comment: It works and thanks. However, I'd like to know what's wrong with my original html file for the relative reference links. Or shouldn't I use the `app.get()` method?

Comment: @JosephTseng there isn't anything wrong with it (or the `app.get` route), the reason it didn't work was because of using an incorrect root path in your call to `express.static`. But in this case, you don't *need* the `app.get` route, so I left it out. If you want to keep using it, make sure you declare it *before* the call to `app.use(express.static(...))`, though (see my edit).

Comment: Thanks for so detailed explanation. If my directory structure is like: `/test/app.js, /test/index.html, and /assets/ico` and the reference link in index.html is like `<link rel="shortcut icon" href="../assets/ico/favicon.png">`, could this reference link to the parent relative folder be possible?

Comment: @JosephTseng `../assets/` is relative to the path of your `index.html`; if you are serving that from `/`, it's not possible to go up to a parent directory.